# Reflagging a question

Tags: support, questions, flags

I flagged [How to get outlook calendar events to sync with php calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369067/how-to-get-outlook-calendar-events-to-sync-with-php-calendar) as "not enough information" and wrote a comment to the OP. After his answer, I decided that it should be flagged as a duplicate of [Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php) but both options are not greyed out? am I doing something "illegal"?

Comment: Reading that question and the comment replies makes me think too broad is still fine. That duplicate is the first small step of the giant leap that OP still has to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both options (Too Broad and Duplicate) are flags to close the question. Just like you can only cast one close vote per question (once you get the 3K reputation required to do so), you can only flag it for closure once.

You did nothing wrong, that's just how the system works.